# Cursor returning null

Tags: android, sqlite, cursor

```
public String getContact(String searchName) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();

    String[] args = { searchName };

    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_MOVIES
            + " WHERE name =? ", args);

    String iName = null, iDiretor = null, iGenre = null;

    cursor.moveToFirst();
    while (!cursor.isAfterLast()) {
        iName = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(KEY_NAME));
        iDiretor = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(KEY_DIRECTOR));
        iGenre = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(KEY_GENRE));
        cursor.moveToNext();
    }

    cursor.close();
```

The iName variable is working fine but the other two are returning null. Any help?

Comment: Are you sure that the Genre and Director are set in the database?

Comment: *are Genre and Director set on the LAST record in the database

Comment: Genre and Director are not set. What a shame! Thanks man!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the `SQLiteDatabase` query methods instead of `rawQuery` for the best results.

```
db.query(TABLE_MOVIES, null, "name = ?", args, null);
```

This is preferred because `rawQuery` is easy to mess up and doesn't protect against SQL injections.

Answer (score 2):

Try this way:

```
Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_MOVIES + " WHERE name LIKE ? ", args);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
  Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_MOVIES
            + " WHERE name LIKE "+searchName, null); // Put Like When your are comparing String
```